# fscalender weekscope swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm using `fscalender` in my project, i have to customise the header title in weekscope.

[image: This is my image]

from above image weekdays showing is from may 16 - 22. I want to display it over the header title.

How to achieve this?

I'm new in iOS
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way, You can do it with customization like in the below method of `FSCalendar` and set week start and end date as follow and set custom header title:

```
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
    return formatter
}()

func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
   let weekStartDt = calendar.currentPage
   let weekEndDt = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: weekStartDt)!
   let weekName = "\(self.dateFormatter.string(from: weekStartDt)) - \(self.dateFormatter.string(from: weekEndDt))"
   self.yourHdrLbl.text = weekName
}
```